# k-equivalence of knots

Tags: knot-theory

A ***k-move*** is defined to be a local change in a knot projection that replaces two untwisted strings with two strings that twist around each other with $k$ crossings in a right-handed manner. A ***-k-move*** is the same with left-handed twists.

[*k-move*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWuAN.png)

We say that two knots are ***k-equivalent*** if we get from one projection of a knot to a projection of the otherthrough a series of *k-moves* or *-k-moves*.

Now I need to prove that the three knots in the image below are 3-equivalent to a trivial link. I think that first *k-move* or *-k-move* on the trivial link would always result in trefoil. I couldn't proceed further.

[Knots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiuWk.png)

Comment: When you say 3-equivalent, do you mean you have to use *exactly* 3 k-moves or less than or equal to 3 k-moves?

Comment: Two knots are _3-equivalent_ if there is a series of _3-moves_ which can take us from projection of the first knot to the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braid group on two strands is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, and 3-moves let you work instead in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.  In a knot diagram, this means a sequence of two right/left-hand crossings can be replaced with a single left/right-hand crossing (respectively), in addition to the ability to introduce or eliminate sequences of three crossings.

In the following picture, $\sim$ is knot equivalence and $\sim^\text{3-move}$ is 3-equivalence.

[image: 3-moves on trefoil, figure-eight, and another knot]